# Search ZipCode to find a City cut ZipCode

Tags: c#, linq

if i´m searching a City by zipcode i got all cities which are compared to the zipcode but the entiered zipcode is cut - e.g. i wrote 01169 i get all Cities but my zipcode was trimmed to 116.

I´ve the following Source for searching:

```
   public dynamic GetCityByZip (string ZipCode)
    {
        BindingList<Orte> cities = new BindingList<Orte>();

        var result = (from ort in _model.Orte
                  where ort.PLZ == ZipCode
                  select ort).ToList();

        cities = new BindingList<Orte>(result);

        return cities;
    }
```

Searching in Form:

```
 private void txtZipCode_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtZipCode.Text.Length == 5)
        {
            BindingList<Orte> result = _getDataFromDatabase.GetCityByZip(txtZipCode.Text);
            cboCities.DataSource = result;
            cboCities.DisplayMember = "Ort";
            cboCities.ValueMember = "Ort";
        }
    }
```

Anyone an idea?

Regards,
dom

Comment: Where was your ZipCode trimmed? In the `txtZipCode` text box?

Comment: Yep - but there is no regulary. If i typed 01169 i get 116 - if i typed 57319 i get 5731 - it´s strange

Comment: Add some logging before and after each action that would capture either `txtZipCode.Text` or `ZipCode` values. This way you will narrow it down to a bug. But generally, the code looks correct. Also why are you using `dynamic`?

Comment: What @bc004346 said, there is nowhere in your code you've shown that would change the value of that text box. Your code must be modifying it somewhere else.

Comment: Do a global search(`Ctrl+Shift+F`  if your using VisualStudio) for `txtZipCode`. Your changing it somewhere.

Comment: Make Brakepoints at TextChanged - there is no point i can find a problem.
This is what logging said:
57319
0
01
011
0116
01163
0116
01169

and i got 116

Every Textchanged is logged - nothing that can explain this problem. 

I can show the whole code - for sure but its to long :-(

I think the problem is:   cboCities.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsMainData, "Ort", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);

Comment: I tried to change the format-property of DataBindings.Add from true to false - then - i got no trim but the zipcode changing back....